# Div at an angle

Tags: html, css

I would like to make my `div` have a pointy angle but I am not sure of what is the best way to do it.

```css
.top-div {
  width: 310px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #A52432;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-div"></div>
```

[image: Pointy red div image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a simple `linear-gradient()` which has greater support than *clip-path*:

```css
.top-div {
  width: 310px;
  height: 25px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, transparent 10%, #A52432 10.01%);
}
```

```html
<div class="top-div"></div>
```

Comment: Interesting this will come in handy in the future thanks :)

Comment: Decide to use in current project due to support as linear-gradient is more supported than clip-path  as seen here https://caniuse.com/#search=linear-gradient vs https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Answer (score 2):

For this kind of effect you could use **CSS** and make a `clip-path` like this:

```css
.top-div {
      width: 310px;
      height: 25px;
      background-color: #A52432;
      -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 96%, 0 100%);
      clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 15% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="top-div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I wasn't aware of how polygons worked before in css learnt something new thanks.

Comment: keep in mind that clip-path doesn't work in IE and Edge
https://caniuse.com/#search=clip-path

Comment: Due to browser support I have decided to use linear-gradient

Answer (score 0):

A div is always a rectangle. I would suggest to place a svg with `<polgon>` on the divs position (see [Polygons](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_polygon.asp)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link I've had a look through it now :)